# MongoDB Compound Indexes

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have a collection of documents that look like this:

```
{
  location: { type: "Point", coordinates: [-76, 42 }, 
  serial: "as23ksfda",
  topic: "rainbows",
  date: ISODate("2017-01-01T04:35:12-04:00")
}
```

I want to run queries that are conditioned on:

- date (a range, i.e. `$and: [{$gt: ISODate("2017-01-01T04:30:21-04:00")}, {$lt:ISODate("2017-02-01T04:30:21-04:00")}]`) and serial
- date and topic
- date and serial and location (i.e. `$near: {$geometry: etc... }`)
- date and topic and location

In other words:

- date is always involved
- either serial or topic is always involved
- location is optional

Given this information, I'd like to create an appropriate set of indexes on the collection so that I get good query performance (obviously without badly impacting write performance, the usual indexing tradeoff).

If I, for example, create:

```
db.collection.createIndex({
  serial: 1, 
  date: 1,
  location: "2dsphere"
})
```

... should I also create an additional index to support my desired set of queries (that do not include location)? e.g.:

```
db.collection.createIndex({
  serial: 1, 
  date: 1
})
```

...or is that gratuitous and not helpful?